# Getting an error called 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException'

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm getting this error while trying to develop my app, the compilator said that it could not find an error code. So I don't have more information. I know that the error is generated while trying to initializeComponent.
Here is the code of my page:

```
    <RelativePanel Padding="40">
    <Image x:Name="logo" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/UPSA.jpg" Width="150" Height="200"/>

    <Border RelativePanel.RightOf="logo" Height="200" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" Background="Orange" UseLayoutRounding="True" CornerRadius="40,40,40,40" Margin="30,0,0,0" />
    <TextBlock Text="Universidad Pontifica de Salamanca" FontSize="72" RelativePanel.RightOf="logo"  RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Cooper Black"  RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWith="logo"/>
    <Grid Margin="30" x:Name="mainGridL" RelativePanel.Below="logo" Height="500" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1.3*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <RelativePanel Grid.Column="0" >
            <TextBlock x:Name="textPersonal" Text="Datos Personales" FontSize="60" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Orange"/>
            <Line x:Name="lineBText" Stroke="Black" RelativePanel.Below="textPersonal" Width="770" StrokeThickness="20" X1="0" X2="770"/>
            <Line x:Name="lineMid" Stroke="Black" RelativePanel.Below="textPersonal" Width="770" StrokeThickness="20" X1="770" X2="770" Y1="0" Y2="420" />
            <Grid RelativePanel.Below="lineBText" Margin="0,20,0,0" RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="textDni" Text="Dni" FontSize="35"   VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="30,0,0,0"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="textEmail" Text="Email" FontSize="35"   VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="30,0,0,0" />
                <TextBox  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column=" 0" x:Name="nifBox" PlaceholderText="DNI..." FontSize="20" Background="Gray"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="29,0,30,0"  />
                <TextBox x:Name="emailBox" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" PlaceholderText="Email..." FontSize="20" Background="Gray"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="30,0,30,0" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"  Text="Nombre" FontSize="35"   VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="30,0,0,0"/>
                <TextBlock  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"  Text="Apellidos" FontSize="35"   VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="30,0,0,0"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="nameBox" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column=" 0" PlaceholderText="Nombre..." FontSize="20" Background="Gray"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="30,0,30,0"  />
                <TextBox x:Name="surnameBox" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" PlaceholderText="Apellido..." FontSize="20" Background="Gray"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="30,0,30,0" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0"  Text="Genero" FontSize="35" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <RadioButton Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="genderMale" Content="Hombre" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                <RadioButton Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="genderFemale" Content="Mujer" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

            </Grid>


        </RelativePanel>
        <RelativePanel Grid.Column="1">
            <TextBlock x:Name="textIns" Text="Datos Inscripcion" FontSize="60" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Orange"/>
            <Line x:Name="lineBTextIns" Stroke="Black" RelativePanel.Below="textIns" Width="770" StrokeThickness="20" X1="0" X2="770"/>
            <StackPanel RelativePanel.Below="lineBTextIns" Orientation="Vertical" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock Text="Titulacion cursada" FontSize="40" Margin="0,0,0,30"/>
                <ComboBox x:Name="degreeName"  PlaceholderText="Esoge tu titulacion"  HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <x:String>ADET</x:String>
                    <x:String>Ing.Informatica</x:String>
                    <x:String>ADET + Ing.Informatica</x:String>
                    <x:String>Ing.Informatica + ADET</x:String>
                </ComboBox>
                <TextBlock Text="Escoge una charla" FontSize="40" Margin="0,0,0,30"/>
                <ComboBox x:Name="activities" PlaceholderText="Escoge una charla"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding Name}"/>

            </StackPanel>
        </RelativePanel>



    </Grid>
    <Button RelativePanel.Below="mainGridL" Content="Enviar" FontSize="40" Margin="0,21,0,0" RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True" />
</RelativePanel>
```

After a long time of trying and error, I found where is the issue located. In the deepest Grid, the error is generated while trying to create TextBox, don't know why because if you just delete textBox it works properly.
Here is the error...

```
            <Grid RelativePanel.Below="lineBText" Margin="0,20,0,0" RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="textDni" Text="Dni" FontSize="35"   VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="30,0,0,0"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="textEmail" Text="Email" FontSize="35"   VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="30,0,0,0" />
            <TextBox  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column=" 0" x:Name="nifBox" PlaceholderText="DNI..." FontSize="20" Background="Gray"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="29,0,30,0"  />
            <TextBox x:Name="emailBox" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" PlaceholderText="Email..." FontSize="20" Background="Gray"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="30,0,30,0" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"  Text="Nombre" FontSize="35"   VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="30,0,0,0"/>
            <TextBlock  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"  Text="Apellidos" FontSize="35"   VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="30,0,0,0"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="nameBox" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column=" 0" PlaceholderText="Nombre..." FontSize="20" Background="Gray"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="30,0,30,0"  />
            <TextBox x:Name="surnameBox" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" PlaceholderText="Apellido..." FontSize="20" Background="Gray"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="30,0,30,0" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0"  Text="Genero" FontSize="35" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <RadioButton Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="genderMale" Content="Hombre" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
            <RadioButton Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="genderFemale" Content="Mujer" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

        </Grid>
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to this two lines:

```
<TextBox  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column=" 0" x:Name="nifBox" PlaceholderText="DNI..." FontSize="20" Background="Gray"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="29,0,30,0"  />
<TextBox x:Name="nameBox" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column=" 0" PlaceholderText="Nombre..." FontSize="20" Background="Gray"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="30,0,30,0"  />
```

You have an extra space before 0 value in the Grid.Column. You need to pass **"0"** instead of " 0".